# Magento 1.9: Show language switcher on frontend only to users logged in as admin

Tags: magento-1.9, language-switcher

I have a website with 2 views and 2 country/language flags switches. 
I am hiding the switches with some code and redirecting the users depending on the IP.

However, the sales department must be able to switch between store views to check prices, etc. They cannot install commercial software to connect with different IPs.

My idea was to enable the country/flag selection only if they are logged in as admin.

How do I go about this? Is there another solution server-side?

Comment: You may use this module to access the admin session in the frontend area. https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions That can help you show the country switcher only for logged in admin user.

Comment: I tried it and it works!